# AES128 encryption giving different results in iOS 6 & iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, aes, commoncrypto

Well, I'm working on an app that sends and receives encrypted data from a web server.
The issue here, is that, my encryption results were different.
Now, comparing the result running on iOS6 & iOS 7 simulator, I noticed the hex was different too, and I didn't touch the code.

Here's the code:

```
@implementation NSData (AES_128)
- (NSData *)AES128Encrypt {
// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

char ivPtr[kCCBlockSizeAES128];

bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));

[iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                      ivPtr /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
}

free(buffer); //free the buffer;
return nil;
}
```

The key and the iv are static, 16 bytes char arrays.
What am I missing here? Thanks in advance